# Why JCMD throws "native memory tracking is not enabled" message even though NMT is enabled?

Tags: java, jvm-hotspot

I am facing this weird problem. I want to track native memory usage of the JVM. I followed instructions provided in [Oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr007.html), added NMT enable flag and recycled Tomcat JVM. After that when I tried to see native memory usage using JCMD, I got "native memory tracking is not enabled" message. Do you think I am missing something?

[Here is the screen print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z68E1.png)

Comment: Any warnings from the JVM during startup of Tomcat? Something like "Native Memory Tracking did not setup properly"? Or "Native Memory Tracking is not supported in this VM"? Or "Syntax error, expecting -XX:NativeMemoryTracking=[off|summary|detail]"?

Comment: @staffan I have not found any error message in stderr or stdout log. That's why I am confused. :)

Comment: @staffan I was wrong. Tomcat *is* logging following error after I issued JCMD command. But it is not easy to find out as Tomcat is logging after I issue a shutdown command. Here is the message that it is printing:
"*Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Native Memory Tracking did not setup properly, using wrong launcher?*"

Comment: Just wanted to share what I found few months ago...I think the problem might be related to this: https://blogs.oracle.com/poonam/entry/using_nmt_with_custom_jvm 

When I launched Tomcat from command line I can use NMT without any problem.

Comment: I'm running into the same situation. Can you be more specific about launching Tomcat "from the command line"? Is that just `tomcat.exe //IS//myservice ...`? I've been trying that with no luck.

Comment: @Didjit Sorry for delayed response.

On Windows: %CATALINA_HOME%\bin\startup.bat
    or
      %CATALINA_HOME%\bin\catalina.bat start

On *nix:
      $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
    or
      $CATALINA_HOME/bin/catalina.sh start

Answer (score 2):

set -XX:NativeMemoryTracking=detail

Comment: Enable NMT using the following command line. Note that enabling this will cause 5-10% performance overhead.
-XX:NativeMemoryTracking=[off | summary | detail]

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/nmt-8.html

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. Presuming you experienced this issue in linux-like-OS (e.g RHEL); this issue occurs because the OS for security reasons, does not allow any user-id other than the user-id associated with the java-process to connect to the jvm. I had to execute sudo with jcmd command as the process user. In my case, the tomcat-service was executing as "userXXX" user. I was able to get a response from the java process when I executed the cmd below.
sudo -u **userXXX** jcmd {pid} VM.native_memory summary scale=KB